# Need Regex Pattern for pipe delimited data

Tags: java, regex

I have pipe delimited data as below:

```
3985199||"ER1AA"|"2017"|"BMC PUBLIC HEALTH"|"17"||"2017-04-09-00.53.55.353280 -0400"|0|"1471-2458"|"13941J"|"C ,CC,D ,ES,JS,Q ,XC"|"A"|"N"|"APR 4  17"
```

How to fetch BMC PUBLIC HEALTH without double quote using regex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Just split on the `|` and "unquote" your fields afterwards. What did you try so far?

Comment: Do not use regex. Use the tool that is the best fit for the job. This is a variant of CSV, with a bar for field separator: use any CSV library instead (as CSV is seemingly trivially simple, but not that simple in actuality). Even Microsoft Excel's CSV import should be up to the task.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

1. First you remove all quotes
2. Then split by `\|+`

As, SO supports Javascript implementation thus the following Javascript snippet is to give you an idea of how you can achieve it:

```js
const regex = /\|+/g;
const str = `3985199||"ER1AA"|"2017"|"BMC PUBLIC HEALTH"|"17"||"2017-04-09-00.53.55.353280 -0400"|0|"1471-2458"|"13941J"|"C ,CC,D ,ES,JS,Q ,XC"|"A"|"N"|"APR 4 17"
`;
console.log(str.replace(/"/g,``).split(regex));
```

Comment: What makes you think this is `JS` ? OP has not told us yet.

Comment: What makes you think a dummy impl can not be represented by a langauge that is covered by stackoverflow ?

Comment: Obviously it can but every language has its subtleties.

Comment: This implementation will fail if there are escaped quotes, or quoted bar-characters in the data. Homebrewing CSV reading is not as trivial as it looks.

Comment: The language hasn't been mentioned, moreover I don't think such simple problem written in one language can not be translated into another.

Comment: We don't know if there will be double quotes within.It may be there. And more possibly it may not be there. This solution is assuming there won't be duoble quotes within.

Comment: I have to use this regex in below code:
public class Pattern {
 psvm( String args[] ) {
     String line = "3985199||\"ER1AA\"|\"2017\"|\"BMC PUBLIC HEALTH\"|\"17\"||\"2017-04-09-00.53.55.353280 -0400\"|0|\"1471-2458\"|\"13941J\"|\"C ,CC,D ,ES,JS,Q ,XC\"|\"A\"|\"N\"|\"APR 4  17\"";
     String pattern = "(?:(?:\"(.*?)\")|(.*?))(?:$|\|)";
     Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
     Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
     if (m.find( )) {
      Sysout("value1" + m.group(0) );
         Sysout("value2" + m.group(1) );
     }
     else {
      Sysout("No Match");
     }
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

The following general pattern should work:

```
(?:(?:"(.*?)")|(.*?))(?:$|\|+)
```

This matches each term followed by one or more pipes, or followed by the end of the string.  In other words, this covers every term in the pipe-delimited string.

Depending on the language/tool you are using, you might not want to use this.  You might want to split the string on pipe and collect terms that way.  But the regex I gave you would work well if you wanted to step through the terms in an editor such as Notepad++.  It would also be a good starting point if you wanted to, for example, remove the quotes from each term using something like Notepad++.

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Thanks for answering.
In your demo, you missed double pipe as you can se in my question "3985199||". It means second field is NULL. I have to match null value as well. Similarly I dont want to match pipe.

Comment: @Prakash I thought the double pipes were an error.  Let me update my regex.

Comment: I have to use this regex in below code: public class Pattern { psvm( String args[] ) { String line = "3985199||\"ER1AA\"|\"2017\"|\"BMC PUBLIC HEALTH\"|\"17\"||\"2017-04-09-00.53.55.353280 -0400\"|0|\"1471-2458\"|\"13941J\"|\"C ,CC,D ,ES,JS,Q ,XC\"|\"A\"|\"N\"|\"APR 4 17\""; String pattern = "(?:(?:\"(.*?)\")|(.*?))(?:$|\|)"; Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern); Matcher m = r.matcher(line); if (m.find( )) { Sysout("value1" + m.group(0) ); Sysout("value2" + m.group(1) ); } else { Sysout("No Match"); } } }

Comment: So is it safe to say you are using Java?  In this case, you should just split on pipe symbol.  What output do you actually want here?

Comment: I am only testing this regex in java code. Actually I have to use this regex pattern somewhere else. If this regex will work in java code then only I can use this in my job. So, I can't use split function.

Comment: What is wrong with the pattern I gave you?  It correctly matches each group, minus the quotes.

Comment: Try to run code which I commented. It is not working. Value of m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3) should be 3985199, null, ER1AA and so on respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "3985199||\"ER1AA\"|\"2017\"|\"BMC PUBLIC HEALTH\"|\"17\"||\"2017-04-09-00.53.55.353280 -0400\"|0|\"1471-2458\"|\"13941J\"|\"C ,CC,D ,ES,JS,Q ,XC\"|\"A\"|\"N\"|\"APR 4  17\"";
    String[] arr = input.split("\"?\\|+\"?|\"");
    for (String ele : arr) {
        System.out.println(ele);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering
Second field should come as null which is not coming using your code.
I cant use split function.
I am posting my code below. Only you need to change regex.
Could you please modify it accordingly?

Comment: public class Pattern {
 psvm( String args[] ) {
     String line = "3985199||\"ER1AA\"|\"2017\"|\"BMC PUBLIC HEALTH\"|\"17\"||\"2017-04-09-00.53.55.353280 -0400\"|0|\"1471-2458\"|\"13941J\"|\"C ,CC,D ,ES,JS,Q ,XC\"|\"A\"|\"N\"|\"APR 4  17\"";
     String pattern = "regex";
     Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
     Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
     if (m.find( )) {
      Sysout("value: " + m.group(0) );
         Sysout("value: " + m.group(1) );
         Sysout("value: " + m.group(2) );
                .....so on
         }
     else {
      Systout("No Match");
     }
 }
}

Answer (score -1):

For Java, I'd recommend [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). E.g. to read a whole file:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.txt"), '|');
List myEntries = reader.readAll();
```